# Shouldn't FileInfo.Delete update Exists?

Tags: c#, .net-core

So I just noticed:

```
// this file exists
var fi = new FileInfo(@"S:\Ome\File.path");
// here fi.Exists == true
fi.Delete();
// still fi.Exists == true
fi.Refresh();
// finally fi.Exists == false
```

The code I wrote assumed `Delete()` changes `Exists` and it was failing very unexpectedly. Checked the actual [source code](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.FileSystem/System/IO/FileInfo.cs) and found `Delete()` is implemented as:

```
public override void Delete() => FileSystem.DeleteFile(FullPath);
```

instead of:

```
public override void Delete()
{
    FileSystem.DeleteFile(FullPath);
    Invalidate();
}
```

Why is this simple operation not updating `Exists` if it succeeds? On the other hand `MoveTo` changes the `fi` object completely updating to the new path. So if you do a `Delete()` you need to followup with a `Refresh()` while a `MoveTo()` is good *(even if it would have been better if `Move()` returned a new `FileInfo` with the new details)*.

**Is this inconsistency by design and is there a reason for it?** At the end of the day it's irrelevant as you just need to add a `Refresh()` after `Delete()` but I find it very unintuitive.

Comment: This is not the place to have a discussion about the action a company took and their reasons thereof. Please reach out through GitHub or the Microsoft support channels, they are the only people who can help you

Comment: Unless someone from Microsoft reads this question, you won't be able to get answers here. Like @TheGeneral said, you should probably raise the question on the .NET Core GitHub or some place.

Comment: I'll try. I was wondering if there's something obvious for this I'm not noticing.

Comment: There is nothing obvious i can see, aside from FileInfo is meant to be lightweight and fast. But as to the inconsistency i doubt you will get a satisfying answer

Comment: It does seem to be by design though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.exists?view=netframework-4.8#remarks And on the refresh page: "Calls must be made to Refresh before attempting to get the attribute information, or the information will be outdated."

Comment: This is normal, FileShare.Delete option.  Which allows another process to delete the file but it won't actually disappear from the file system (and make Exists return false) until everybody closed the file.  Programs that need to look at a file content but not interfere with its normal usage need to use that option, search indexers for example.  Otherwise an excellent reason to *never* use Exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy answer:
Microsoft forgot to set property after Delete. easy.

Delete works like this. Delete and return!

```cs
if (Win32Native.DeleteFile(this.FullPath))
    return;
```

They forgot to inform main object about deletion.

```cs
if (Win32Native.DeleteFile(this.FullPath))
{
    this._dataInitialised = -1;
    return;
}
```

Comment: How do you _know_ that they forgot it and that it is not done intentionally?

Comment: The _dataInitialised  existed for this reason. Inform about this kind of changes.
if you look into Exists property getter; you can understand it. Obviously They forgot!

public override bool Exists
if (this._dataInitialised == -1)
            this.Refresh();